# Extracting all PDF Links from Multiple Websites

Tags: downloads, scripts

[Glutanimate posted a script that extracts all PDF links from a single page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395150/how-can-i-extract-all-pdf-links-on-a-website).

Any idea on how to change this so the script can grab all the PDF links from a list of URLs ?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a separate (text) file with all url's listed in single lines:

```
www.url1
www.url2
```

Then change the line in the script to ***append*** the found pdf links to the produced `pdflinks.txt` (`tee -a pdflinks.txt | more` instead of `tee pdflinks.txt`):

```
lynx -cache=0 -dump -listonly "$WEBSITE" | grep ".*\.pdf$" | awk '{print $2}' | tee -a pdflinks.txt | more
```

Then make the script executable and run it by another (python in this case) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

url_list = "/path/to/url_list.txt"
script = "/path/to/script.sh"

with open(url_list) as sourcefile:
    sourcefile = sourcefile.readlines()
for item in sourcefile:
    subprocess.call([script, item.replace("\n", "")])
```

Paste the text above in an empty document, add appropriate paths and save it as run_pdflinkextractor.py and run it by the command

```
python3 /path/to/run_pdflinkextractor.py
```

**More options**

You didn't actually ask for it, but in case you would like to download the found pdf links, it is a pity to stop half way. The script below might be handy to do that. The procedure is the same: paste the text below in an empty file, save it as `download_pdffiles.py`, add the path to the `pdflinks.txt` that was created in the first step, the path to the folder you would like to download the files to, and run it by the command:

```
 python3 /path/to/download_pdffiles.py
```

The script to actually download the files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

pdf_list = "/path/to/pdflinks.txt"
download_directory = "/path/to/downloadfolder"

with open(pdf_list) as sourcefile:
    sourcefile = sourcefile.readlines()
for item in sourcefile:
    subprocess.call(["wget", "-P", download_directory, item.replace("\n", "")])
```

You can of course add more options to the script, what to do in case of errors for example (errors are ignored in the script as it is). See `man wget` for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Answer depends on what you define as "list of URL's".

If you want to do it as multi-arg command line script, use code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for WEBSITE in "$*"
do
    <scriptname> "$WEBSITE"
done
```

There is also a way to read a list of URL's from file, line by line:

```
#!/bin/bash
_file="$1"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    <scriptname> "$line"
done < "$_file"
```

Improve my answer as you wish. I'm not a bash master :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like hardcoding file names into scripts. I prefer giving them as arguments. This can be done via a very minor modification of Glutanimate's script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# NAME:         pdflinkextractor
# AUTHOR:       Glutanimate (http://askubuntu.com/users/81372/), 2013
# LICENSE:      GNU GPL v2
# DEPENDENCIES: wget lynx
# DESCRIPTION:  extracts PDF links from websites and dumps them to the stdout and as a textfile
#               only works for links pointing to files with the ".pdf" extension
#
# USAGE:        pdflinkextractor "www.website.com" > output_file


echo "Getting link list..."

## Go through each URL given and find the PDFs it links to
for website in "$@"; do
    lynx -cache=0 -dump -listonly "$website" | awk '/.pdf$/{print $2}'
done
```

You can save that as `downloadpdfs`, make it executable (`chmod +x downloadpdfs`) and then run it, giving it multiple addresses as arguments:

```
downloadpdfs "http://example.com" "http://example2.com" "http://example3.com" > pdflinks.txt
```

The above will create a file called `pdflinks.txt` containing all the links extracted from each of the input URLs.

Comment: While it's probably not as important in this case, wouldn't `$@` be safer than `$*`? (Or maybe I understood their usage wrong. Still a newbie with scripting.)

Comment: @Glutanimate yes indeed it would. It won't make any practical difference at all in this case but using `"$@"` is [almost always](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/22222) better than using `"$*"`. Thanks for catching it and thanks for the edit :).